# How does list joining algorithm work?

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I have found in the [wayland protocol source code](https://github.com/sir-murray/wayland/blob/99d2775ae95784a3e9f4bcd6d2ef48cf36ca8c15/src/wayland-util.h) the following function.

```
void
wl_list_insert_list(struct wl_list *list, struct wl_list *other)
{
     if (wl_list_empty(other))
         return;
     other->next->prev = list;
     other->prev->next = list->next;
     list->next->prev = other->prev;
     list->next = other->next;
 }
```

Which operates on a list which has links like so:

```
struct wl_list {
    struct wl_list *prev;
    struct wl_list *next;
};
```

It is just a doubly linked list like any other.

However I do not understand this function at all.
To me it looks like the link 'other' is completely lost from both lists, and the *list and *list->next links now simply cross over to the other list.

Also: this is not a circular list.
head and tail links point to themselves.[EDIT] My bad, is in fact a circular list. Makes sense that way.

Could anyone help me understand how this algorithm works.
Thanks alot.

Comment: You will have to post the declaration/initialization of `other`.  Without more, `other->prev->next` makes no sense if you say the lists are **non-circular** -- it doesn't exist.

Comment: The lists are actually circular.  If you follow through what happens after you add one node, you will see that a circle is created.

Comment: Agreed, circular is the only thing that makes sense, even though it directly contradicts the questioners post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drew pictures, then stared at them in confusion until I realized the magic.  `list` and `other` are not nodes, they are list *objects*.  Yes, `other` is removed from "it's list of nodes" because we want to add the *nodes* of the list `other` to the list `list`.  After the function ends, `other` is completely removed, and all the circularly linked nodes are linked into `list`'s nodes.
[image]

Comment: I stared at it too.  According to their code, a list that only points at itself is considered empty.  So what you said makes sense, because `other` would be left with just the one node so it would be considered an empty list.  I think every list has one empty head node that isn't considered part of the actual list.

Comment: @JS1: It's the only explanation that makes sense

Comment: I drew pictures too, and I'm still confused. I recognized `list` and `other` as objects, but if `other` is **non-circular**, where/what did you connect `other->prev->next` to? (`other->prev` should not point to anything having a `->next`)??  And, yes, I agree, a **circular** list is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot. Esentailly the nodes from the "other" object are inserted after "list" but before all of "lists" nodes. Is it just me or is this a sightly silly implementation?

Comment: @user2936306: Yeah, seems weird to me that it inserts at the front, but meh.